# Why is curl_multi_exec taking much longer than the slowest url executed?

Tags: php, curl, multitasking

I'm attempting some sort of multitasking using curl. The task the curls do is to look for a string in several 4-megabyte files. When I delegated one curl call for each file, that was already some gain over one PHP scanning them all. It took from 3 to 4 seconds to scan all files. Then I decided to create TWO curls for each file scan, each curl call scanning a half of the file. I felt I didn't get the increase in speed I expected, so I tried now 4 curls for each file because I wanted to check the overhead/efficacy ratio. Some profiling showed me that:

```
$running = null;
do {
curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($running > 0);
```

Takes around 4 seconds to complete 28 curls. Now, the longest time a curl took  was 0.4. Why had the difference? I thought I was blocking it somehow, but the added values of the 28 executions (measured independently inside the PHP's that were called) would easily jump 10 s, so the 'multitasking' was there.

To make things clearer, this is what I am using:

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array(),$color) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    //curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1); <-- this would make my     computer a zombie, seemingly worrying about NOTHING but the curls
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true); //<-- I added     this line cuz I heard its good 
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running); //<--- grrrr
  } while($running > 0);

  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);

    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }
  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);
}
```

(I've read there is a method I can add a callback function that gets triggered seemingly on progress, and that would enable me some manipulation of the "get contents and remove handles" part, but is it possible to bypass the waiting at the curl_multi_exec loop while have the curl files execute? Or we have to keep calling the curl_multi_exec for the execution to proceed? I'm thinking: 1 has curl call for PHPs/2 curl doesn't wait and returns and for us it is dead, but it run desired PHPs/3 PHPs write data to files at their own pace while main program scans for these files, curl theoretically still dealing with its overhead while we already returned to client...)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yep, to take advantage of this method you need to use a body callback on success. i'll dig up a code example for you later, i built a tool that performs async file downloads once upon a time before the world knew about node.js.

Comment: Yay christmas! Thank you for your interest :) I can't wait to know what the callback will be like. I'm about to do some experiments with the callback they provide just to dig deeper in the time discrepancies thing.